# Same test cases showing different answer

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, max, min

I have doubt regarding [this min-max problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/mini-max-sum/problem):

My code :

```
void miniMaxSum(vector<int> arr) {
    
sort(arr.begin(), arr.end()); 
int sum=0;
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
sum += arr[i];
cout<<sum-arr[4]<<" "<<sum-arr[0]<<endl;   

}
```

In other words:

```
void miniMaxSum(vector<int> arr) {
    
sort(arr.begin(), arr.end()); 

int min=0;
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
min += arr[i];
cout<<min<<" ";

int max=0;
for(int i=1; i<5; i++)
max += arr[i];
cout<<max<<endl;
    
}
```

These code running successfuly for sample data 1 and 2, but when I submit my code, these test cases also showing as wrong output.

> Can you please hint where this code wrong !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` is a 32bit integer, the problem mentions that it's possible for the answer to be greater than this. You will want to use a 64 bit integer (`int64_t`) for your vector and your max variables.

You should also switch to passing by reference instead of by value
`void miniMaxSum(vector<int> arr) {` will copy the entire array, who `void miniMaxSum(const vector<int>& arr) {` will pass in a read only reference to the array without copying it.

Comment: The function is mutating the vector by sorting it. Just letting the parameter list make you a copy is easiest, and const ref won't work at all ...

Answer (score 0):

Change `int` to `long long` according to given problem.